# Why I only get first object, when the object is in "for loop" and return its value in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, vue.js

what I want here is to return the value of my object that is in "for loop" into the three "input text" in sequence, but why I only get the value of the first object only?

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    myObj: [
              {name: 'Hello', age: 10},
              {name: 'World', age: 20},
              {name: 'Yeah!', age: 30}
           ]
  },
  computed: {
    return_val: function() {
      for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        return this.myObj[i].name;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input type="text" value="" v-model="return_val">
  <input type="text" value="" v-model="return_val">
  <input type="text" value="" v-model="return_val">
</div>
```

Comment: because `return` exits the function immediately. Also, you can't return 3 values by returning 3 times - perhaps you need to check some vue.js documentation. Hint: `v-for`

Comment: do you have any good suggestions for fixing the above code?

Comment: yes, use `v-for`

Comment: @Rajesh - array.map will return an array - that won't help

Comment: look at the HTML @Rajesh :p (though, you may well be right, only OP knows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `v-for` like this:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    myObj: [{
        name: 'Hello',
        age: 10
      },
      {
        name: 'World',
        age: 20
      },
      {
        name: 'Yeah!',
        age: 30
      }
    ]
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div v-for="item in myObj">
    <input type="text" v-model=item.name />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution for what you are trying to do is using v-for and v-model.

```
<div id="app">
  <input type="text" value="" v-model="item.name" v-for="item in myObj">
</div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wph3o7py/)

Hope it helps. Please feel free to ask if you to know anything else.